# AngularJS Next and Previous Array Values

Tags: arrays, angularjs

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
Change state when the user clicks previous or next, each state is assigned an id and will need to figure out which id is previous or next before changing previous or next state.

**Current Problem:**
I have managed to display the current state id '1' and I have managed to group all the other id's within an array but I don't know how to get the next and previous buttons to trigger the right previous or next states on click.

Please find my code below, I've added comments/notes to point things out. 
Any help/advice would be helpful! 
Thank you.

**Controller JS**

```
  // -- Current Page ID, '1' -- //
  var currentID = $stateParams.id;
  // -- Body Type, 'triangle' -- //
  var bodyType = $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType.bodyType;
  // --  Dress Array, [{"id": "1", "bodyType": "triangle"},{"id": "2", "bodyType": "triangle"},{"id": "3", "bodyType": "round"},{"id": "4", "bodyType": "triangle"}] --//
  var dressArray = $scope.$storage.appData.dresses;
  // -- Remove anything that doesn't match the current body Type e.g Remove 'round' -- //
  var removeRound = $filter('filter')(dressArray, function(value, index) {return value.bodyType == bodyType;});
  // -- Dress Array -- //
  $scope.dressArray = [];
  // -- Push each filter value to Array, ["1", "2", "4"] -- //
  angular.forEach(removeRound, function(value, key) {
    $scope.dressArray.push(value.id);
  });
  // -- Console Test, ["1", "2", "4"] -- //
  console.log($scope.dressArray);
  // -- If currentID = '1', The next button should display '2' -- //
  // -- If currentID = '2', The next button should display '4'--//
  $scope.nextDress = function() {
    $state.go('main.rail', {id: idhere });
  };
  // -- If currentID = '1', The previous button should display '4' -- //
  // -- If currentID = '2', The previous button should display '1' -- //
  $scope.previousDress = function() {
    $state.go('main.rail', {id: idhere });
  };
```

**HTML**

```
<li class="next"><md-button ng-click="nextDress()">Next</md-button></li>
<li class="previous"><md-button ng-click="previousDress()">Previous</md-button></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

check that the `currentId + 1` is not greater than the length of the array for the next item (if greater, go to the first) and check that the `currentId - 1` is not less than 0, if yes, go to the last item (to make it cyclic):

```
 $scope.nextDress = function() {
    var next = parseInt(currentId) + 1 > dressArray.length ? 0 : parseInt(currentId) + 1;
    $state.go('main.rail', {id: next });
  };

  $scope.previousDress = function() {
    var prev = parseInt(currentId) - 1 < 0 ? dressArray.length - 1 : parseInt(currentId) - 1;
    $state.go('main.rail', {id: prev });
  };
```

Comment: Morning @taxicala the above snippet seemed to work but instead of picking up the state ID within the array it was picking up the array index id. How would we now change this to work the with array state id's instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would make the data like a closed linked list, run this every time after passing through filter.

```
var currentItem; // keep a reference of current item
var arrayToLL = function(arr){
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var item = arr[i];
    if (i == 0) item.prev = arr[arr.length - 1];
    else item.prev = arr[i - 1];

    if (i == arr.length - 1) item.next = arr[0];
    else item.next = arr[i + 1];

    if (item.id == currentId) { // you may get currentId from $stateParams
      currentItem = item;
    }
  }
}

$scope.nextDress = function() {
  $state.go('main.rail', {id: currentItem.next.id });
};

$scope.previousDress = function() {
  $state.go('main.rail', {id: currentItem.prev.id });
};
```

Comment: @adamkwadsworth I didn't run it but it should get the id instead of the array index. You can give it a try and see how it does. Even better if you can understand it and implement your own idea.

Comment: Morning @lcycool I tried the above and nothing seemed to happen! I guess as it was untested it may not be working! Have you got any further suggestions???